# Me, my heart, and NYC

Tags: grammar, meaning, meaning-in-context, sentence-construction, sentence-meaning

Do these two sentences convey the same meaning:

1. My heart belongs to NYC.
2. My heart belongs in NYC.

Comment: No. Dictionary definitions of "in" and "to" will explain the differentces.

Comment: My guess is "no", per Davo's comment above, but perhaps in some context it wouldn't make a difference. What is the context you're asking about?

Answer (score 1):

The first one would be more suggestive of someone who loves NYC, but doesn't necessarily want to live there.

The second one would suggest the person does want, or need, to live there.

In practical usage, this difference would be very small and almost interchangeable.